# Call action method by pushing radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 radio buttons. I want such logic: when I push the radio button 
the required action method will be called. I don't know how to do it using
JQuery. Are there any of others varients ?

```
<h3>Gender:</h3>

    @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "All", true, new {id = "radioAll"})
    @Html.Label("All")

<br/>

    @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male", false, new {id = "radioMale"})
    @Html.Label("Male")

<br/>
@Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female", false, new {id = "radioFemale"})
@Html.Label("Female")

// I tried to find out a decision but couldn't.
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ShowUsers", "Home")';

    if ($("#radioMale").attr("checked") === "checked") {
        $.post(url, 'choice=' + "Male");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Register a click handler for radio buttons with name='Gender' and pass the clicked radio button value to url.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ShowUsers", "Home")';

    $("input:radio[name='Gender']").on("click",function(){
        var choice = $(this).val();
        $.post(url, {'choice':choice});// data must be passed as key value pair
    });
});
```

**[More Information for $.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)**

Comment: What action method must be called? Get or Post?

Comment: `$.post` for POST method only. But data should be like key value pari `{choice:choice}` , See [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) form more information

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=Gender]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'Male') {
            $.post( '@Url.Action("ShowUsers", "Home", new {choice = "Male"})', function( data ) {
               //do something
            });

        }
        else if (this.value == 'Female') {
            $.post( '@Url.Action("ShowUsers", "Home", new {choice = "Female"})', function( data ) {
               //do something
            });
        }
        else{
            $.post( '@Url.Action("ShowUsers", "Home")', function( data ) {
               //do something
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if what you are saying with your code is:
When the document has loaded, check the value of the #radioMale.
If it is checked (when the document just loaded), POST to your Action.

You probably want to set up a listener on the radio buttons, and when they are clicked, then you call your action.

Example below: 
VIEW

```
<div>
@Html.RadioButton("male", "male", new { id = "male" });
@Html.RadioButton("female", "female", new { id = "female" });
</div>
@section scripts{ 
<script>
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("ShowUsers", "Home")';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#male").click(function (e) {
            $.get(baseUrl, { choice: e.target.id }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
        $("#female").click(function (e) {
            $.get(baseUrl, { choice: e.target.id }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>

}
```

ACTION

```
public ActionResult ShowUsers(string choice)
{
    return View();
}
```